# Using Python search for a string in each file in a folder and subfolders

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-os

I have written some code for all files in a folder but I want to check for the string even in sub folders. Suggest me for sub folders

```
from os import listdir
path='D:\\PyScripts'
keywords=['version','navigate']
for file in listdir('D:\\PyScripts'):
with open('D:\\PyScripts\\'+ file,'r') as f:
    data=f.read()
    data=data.lower()
    valid_keys=list(map(counters,keywords))

    if valid_keys:
        ****Some logic*****
```

Comment: lookup `os.walk`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thank you will try it and post my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how it can be done. I tested using my folder files. Change it up for your needs.

```
import os
from os import walk
path='D:\\files'
keywords=['test','this']

for root, dirs, files in walk(path):
    for name in files:            
        with open(os.path.join(root, name),'r') as f:
            data=f.read()
            data=data.lower()

            print(data)
```